# How to check if tuple having a list or dictionary is empty

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, tuples

I have a tuple:

```
details = ({}, [])
```

As there is no data in the following tuple I want to return a null response. For this I am writing:

```
 if not details:
      return Response({})
 else:
    print "Not null"
```

But this does not seem to work as it is always going in the `else` part and printing not null. I am new to python. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `if not any(details):`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **Note**: if you write:
>
> ```
> if <expr>:
>     pass
> ```
>
> then Python will *not* check that `<expr> == True`, it will evaluate the [***truthiness***](https://www.udacity.com/wiki/cs258/truthiness-in-python) of the `<expr>`. Objects have some sort of defined "truthiness" value. The truthiness of `True` and `False` are respectively `True` and `False`. For `None`, the truthiness is `False`, for numbers usually the truthiness is `True` if and only if the number is *different* from zero, for collections (tuples, sets, dictionaries, lists, etc.), the truthiness is `True` if the collection contains at least one element. By default custom classes have always `True` as truthiness, but by overriding the `__bool__` (or `__len__`), one can define custom rules.

The *truthiness* of tuple is `True` given the tuple itself contains one or more items (and `False` otherwise). What these elements are, is irrelevant.

In case you want to check that *at least* one of the items of the tuple has *truthiness* `True`, we can use `any(..)`:

```
if not any(details):  # all items are empty
    return Response({})
else:
    print "Not null"
```

So from the moment the list contains at least one element, or the dictonary, or both, the `else` case will fire, otherwise the `if` body will fire.

If we want to check that *all* elements in the tuple have truthiness `True`, we can use `all(..)`:

```
if not all(details):  # one or more items are empty
    return Response({})
else:
    print "Not null"
```

Comment: Learned something new today. Thanks. Can you explain why `details == True` returns False, but `if details: print('True')` prints True in the prompt?

Comment: @MiniGunnR: because `if <expr>` does *not* check that `<expr> == True`, ut evaluates the *truthiness*.

Comment: Pretty detailed answer

Comment: Thank you.Great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer implies that `any` does not perform a deep search for truth. This is demonstrated below:

```
not not [] # False (double negation as truthness detector).
not not ([],) # True
not not any(([],)) # False
not not any(([1],)) # True
not not any(([None],)) # Still True, as expected.
```